# Converting entire string array to double array throws input format exception, but converting single elements works fine

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string array (which I populated from a .txt file) to a double array in C#.

This is what I've tried, using a for loop, which I've seen on other solutions.

```
            string[] StringArr = File.ReadAllLines("256.txt");

            double[] DoubleArr = new double[StringArr.Length];

            for(int i = 0; i < StringArr.Length; i++)
            {
                DoubleArr[i] = Convert.ToDouble(StringArr[i]);
            }
```

This threw the exception "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format." for

```
DoubleArr[i] = Convert.ToDouble(StringArr[i]);
```

I thought there was something wrong with the format of the data from the text file, but when I tried

```
DoubleArr[0] = Convert.ToDouble(StringArr[0]);
Console.WriteLine(DoubleArr[0]);
```

this worked without throwing an exception, and printed the correct number.

I assume that I must have done something wrong with the for loop?

Comment: Or perhaps the error is in an element other than the first element in the array? Have you tried stepping through the code until you encounter the exception and inspecting the value causing it in the debugger? Or adding a `try...catch` and logging the value of the element along with its index in the array to the console?

Comment: What does the debugger show for value of the array element when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Thank you both, I used a `try...catch` and it turns out there was an empty line at the end of the text file causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

without seing your data, you could have a problem of `Incorrect decimal separator`

Different cultures use different decimal separators ( `,` and `.`  for example)

If you replace . with , all will be okay

or you use the Culture :

```
double.Parse("12.345", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

also, you could have an empty value which is an incorrect double